# Mysql2 gem installation issue on ubuntu with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to install mysql2 gem .
I have recently installed ruby 2 and rails 4 version .
I am not able to install mysql2 gem, getting the below error when i run the command gem install mysql2:
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Just retry? Also include full log (as a code block please) and look at other questions since this thing had been asked multiple times

Comment: I think you will get more response, if you update the log here

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the following packages are installed first

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev`

You may need to run

`sudo apt-get update`

before installing them

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information. But here some thoughts:

- Why are you using `gem install mysql2` instead of adding the gem to your Gemfile and run `bundle`?
- I had some issues with Rails 4 and mysql2 v0.4.x and downgraded to v0.3.20